# How to find pattern and make operation in another field in awk?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file with 4 columns separated by space like this bellow:

```
1_86500000 50 1_87500000 19
1_87500000 13 1_89500000 42
1_89500000 25 1_90500000 10
1_90500000 3 1_91500000 11
1_91500000 23 1_92500000 29
1_92500000 34 1_93500000 4
1_93500000 39 1_94500000 49
1_94500000 35 1_95500000 26
2_35500000 1 2_31500000 81
2_31500000 12 2_4150000 50
```

The First and Third columns are not in phase so I can not divide the value of one by another.
As there are only two or one possible columns $1 or $3, a solution would be look for the pattern and divide its value in the another column or set it to 0 if there is none like this expected result shows:

P.S. the second field in this expected result is just illustrative to shown the division.

```
1_86500000 0/50 0
1_87500000 19/13 1.46154
1_89500000 42/25 1.68
1_90500000 10/3 3.333
1_91500000 11/23 0.47826
1_92500000 29/34 0.85294
1_93500000 4/39 0.10256
1_94500000 49/35 1.4
2_35500000 0/1 0
2_31500000 81/12 6.75
2_4150000 50/0 50
```

I do not archived anything by myself other than this. So I do not have any starting point by now.

I tried separate the fields merged with _ to see if I could match by subtracting the coordinates. If I got 0 would mean that the columns was in phase and correct. But I could not go further.

```
awk '{if( ($5-$2)==0) print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file
```

I tried to match both columns but I only got phased results:

```
awk '{if(($1==$3)) print $1,$4/$2}' file
```

Can you help me?

Comment: what did you try so far to solve the problem? I am sure you can show some awk code

Comment: see my Edited code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{d[$1]=$2; n[$3]=$4} 
   END {for(k in n) 
          if(k in d) {print k,n[k]"/"d[k],n[k]/d[k]; delete d[k]} 
          else print k,n[k]"/0",n[k];
        for(k in d) print k,"0/"d[k],0}' file | sort

1_86500000 0/50 0
1_87500000 19/13 1.46154
1_89500000 42/25 1.68
1_90500000 10/3 3.33333
1_91500000 11/23 0.478261
1_92500000 29/34 0.852941
1_93500000 4/39 0.102564
1_94500000 49/35 1.4
1_95500000 26/0 26
2_31500000 81/12 6.75
2_35500000 0/1 0
2_4150000 50/0 50
```

your division by zero result is little strange though!

**Explanation** keep two arrays for numerator and denominator.  Once scanned the file, go over numerator array and find the corresponding denominator and make the division. For the denominators not used apply the convention given.

Comment: Thank you very much! You solution works very well. Thank you for the explanation also.

The division by 0 is very strange but I thought only defining it to zero anyway haha.

Karakfa you should have a awk hero t-shirt.